# Swift Package Manager automatically marks library as unsafe for extensions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a [SPM Package](https://github.com/ddaddy/DJSwiftHelpers/blob/master/Package.swift) filled with useful swift code.
I have split it into 3 libraries so any `UIKit` and `SwiftUI` code is separate from the main library.

When I add the main library to a project that is marked with `Require Only App-Extention-Safe API = YES` Xcode gives the warning that I am using a library that is not safe for an app extension.

I previously got around this by giving the SPM target the following linker setting:

```
linkerSettings: [.unsafeFlags(["-Xlinker", "-no_application_extension"])]
```

however this no longer seems appropriate in Xcode 14. It is possible to continue using this as long as the SPM package is added based on a commit hash and not a version number.

Obviously using this linker setting simply disables the warning rather than fixing the issue and i'd like to get to the bottom of the issue.

I've used `otool -L` to look at the framework and it doesn't import anything that's extension unsafe, just `Foundation` and `CoreFoundation`:

```
@rpath/DJSwiftHelpers_-7B80557CB3E22184_PackageProduct.framework/DJSwiftHelpers_-7B80557CB3E22184_PackageProduct (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1953.1.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1953.1.0)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.7.1)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.100.0, weak)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 9.0.0, weak)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftDarwin.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0, weak)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftDispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
@rpath/libswift_Concurrency.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.7.1, weak)
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, curredardarrenjodarrenjones@Ddarrenjones@Ddarrenjones@Ddarrendarrdadadadddardarredardardardaddddadardadardarrdadardardaddd
```

What else can I look at to try and find what is causing my projects to think this is unsafe in extensions?